# Crosstabs in BlueSky Statistics

Tags: statistics

Running CrossTabs in BlueSky Statistics with "factor" variables is generating an empty table of results.  This result can be reproduced by opening up sample.xls (from: C:\Program Files\BlueSky Statistics\Sample Datasets\Excel ) and running the CrossTabs on the variables therein (after converting them to "factor" variables).  What is the fix for this behavior?

I uninstalled/reinstalled the BlueSky Statistics Software, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to address this issue is to close the BlueSky Statistics application and then  delete the BlueSky folder under c:\users\\Appdata\Roaming\
When you launch the application, we will create the folder again. The issue is caused by files in the user profile getting corrupt. We don't remove this on uninstall as users may have installed custom dialogs